# JSF and Primefaces performance for large amount of user

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have already created a project in JSF and Primefaces  for small amount of users which is working still good. But i have a requirement to create another project where user amount will be very large and per second there will be more than thousand user hit the url and browse their content. Now i want to create this with JSF. Is this will be a good decision? If so how JSF will control the traffic at the same time more than thousand user?

Comment: This question is way too broad and is missing a lot of details. It's perfectly possible to serve thousands users with JSF/PrimeFaces. But the success is dependant on a lot of factors, the most important being the "heavyness" of your actual application.No one will be able to answer this for you. Do some load testing.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In my personal experience the amount of User Requests should be managed at a System Level, and not at presentation layer, providing a performant servlet container(see here [Java Servlet container performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148663/java-servlet-container-performance)) using the apprpriate amount of memory.
If you have large datasets implement Primefaces Lazy Datamodels(https://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.0/org/primefaces/model/LazyDataModel.html).
I would prefer to use Spring MVC instead of JSF(see here [Spring MVC vs JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249706/spring-mvc-vs-jsf))

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Please rate my answer if it was useful.